How is reinterpret_cast casting pointer to a different type without creating the object?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Mango {
  public:
  Mango() {
    cout<<"mango called"<<endl;
  }
  void print() {
    cout<<"mango"<<endl;
  }
};

class Apple {
  public:
  Apple() {
    cout<<"apple called"<<endl;
  }
  void print() {
    cout<<"apple"<<endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Mango* m = new Mango();
  Apple* a = reinterpret_cast<Apple*>(m);
  a->print();
  return 0;
}

The output is
mango called
apple

I can see that a->print() is printing the contents of apple object, but apple constructor was never called, so apple object was never created.
How is this even working? How is the pointer a pointing to apple object which was never created? Shouldn't it still point to the bits which have the data generated by Mango object?

This is undefined behavior.

@tkausl even if its undefined, it means it works sometimes, how is it even working is my question

If I had to speculate I would say it is calling the print function from Apple because you wrote a(an apple)->print()

Both Mango and Apple are empty objects with a minimum size so they have different addresses. What you see is exactly what I would expect though it is technical UB.

If you want your noodle really blown - declare the print methods as virtual in both classes. i.e. virtual void print() {. Then run again.

Apple::print() is a function that takes an object pointer as the first argument - this pointer. When you do reinterpret_cast, you cast that pointer. But it's unused inside print() anyway, so I don't see why you're surprised that your code works. Try to add a data member into Apple and print that data member inside print().

"Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash." The first step should be to remove UB, then and only then you could say "it works".

Consistency of undefined behavior for a fixed compiler and Why is the phrase: "undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything it wants" true? and Is this strict aliasing violation?

"it should still point to the bits..." No UB means anything can happen(allowed to happen). See also What is strict aliasing rule

@tkausl even if its undefined, it means it works sometimes, how is it even working is my question... NO programming doesn't work like that and certainly not in C++.  It might "seem to work" right now.. but change compile settings or get a new compiler version and it may well stop to work.

https://wg21.link/expr.ref#8.sentence-1 : If you made Apple::print() static this would work

It's technically undefined behavior. But here's a reasonable explanation about why it happens to work with non-virtual methods.
When the compiler generates code, it more or less converts C++ methods to have an implicit "this" argument passed to each.
Imagine you had a Foo class with a method such as:
void Foo::doSomething(int x, int y) {
    z = x*y;
}

Under the hood, the compiler will generate it similar to a C function to something logically (but not exactly) named this:
void Foo_doSomething(Foo* this, int x, int y) {
   this->z = x*y;
}

Back to the mango and apple example.  The print method from both classes are more or less generated like this:
void Mango_print(Mango* this) {
    cout<<"mango"<<endl;
}

void Apple_print(Apple* this) {
    cout<<"apple"<<endl;
}

This line of code:
a->print();

Is more or less compiled to invoke the print function like this:
Apple_print(&a);

Because neither function actually access the "this" parameter passed in, it just happens to work ok.
If you extend both classes like the following to have a "z" variable
class Mango {
public:
  double z;
  Mango() {
    cout<<"mango called"<<endl;
    z = 3.14;
  }
  void print() {
    cout<<"mango: "<< z << endl;
  }
};

class Apple {
  public:
  int z;
  Apple() {
    cout<<"apple called"<<endl;
    z = 42;
  }
  void print() {
    cout<<"apple: " << z << endl;
  }
};

You'll get quite unexpected results when casting a Mango to an Apple and vice-versa. It won't print 42 or 3.14 on a casted object.
Ironically, Objective-C (which used to be popular on Mac) does allow for some of these types of casting shenanigans for invoking code on classes with similar function signatures. A side effect of "message passing", but I digress.

Probably one of the worst aspects of undefined behavior is that sometimes you get results that are reasonable or can be explained away.  It might lull you into thinking you have it under control, until it blows up on you at the most inopportune time.

Undefined behavior is undefined behavior and should be removed from code. It might work now... but a few compiler versions/optimizations down the line and it might well stop to work. So I do not consider this an answer.
